# Batch script math incorrect

Tags: batch-file, variables, math

I have the following code that gets the size of my Downloads folder then divides it and sets it to a variable.
I have 7 other lines just like this that work, but this one doesnt.

The %div2% is coming up blank.

Does anyone see what I did wrong?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "target2=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads"
if not defined target2 set "target2=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads"

set "size2=0"
for /f "tokens=3,5" %%a in ('
    dir /a /s /w /-c "%target2%"
    ^| findstr /b /l /c:"  "
') do if "%%b"=="" set "size2=%%a"  


SET /A %size2%/1048576

SET /A div2=%size2%/1048576

echo  %DIV2%

pause
```

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `set /?` and read the output help. It could be useful to use `set /A size/=1048576` and `set /A div2=size/1048576`. But please note that `cmd.exe` supports for __arithmetic expressions__ only __signed 32-bit integers__ which means numbers in the range `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. There is no support for numbers exceeding 2 GiB and no support for floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Some more hints: `set "target2=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads"` should be better written as `set "target2=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"`. Run in a command prompt window `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"` and next `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"` and you know the reason. The next line with the `if` condition is never true and is therefore completely useless. This batch file is written hopefully just for yourself as the `Downloads` directory can be customized to any directory a user wants.

Comment: I was hoping the math would cut the number so it could be used. It is about 7 gbs. The script goes through all the folders I have listed then gets the size and adds them then displays  in a message that says The total of the folders is 19.3 gbs for example

Comment: Well, if the files in the directory take together more than 2 GiB, the choice to use a batch file processed by `cmd.exe` to get the used space in MB, MiB, GB or GiB was not good. I suggest in this case to do the task with a PowerShell script interpreted by PowerShell. PowerShell is the dedicated successor of the Windows command processor and has not such limitations on mathematical operations as `cmd.exe`. It is possible with string operations before the arithmetic expressions to get a result in MB/GB MiB/GiB with batch code, but it will not be accurate.

Comment: Feel free to call out to Powershell to do the math for you. Example: `for /f "delims=" %%G IN ('powershell 7000000000 / 1048576') do set "result=%%G"`

Comment: Powershell is disabled here

Comment: What about vbscript?

Comment: I think I have it figured out. Now if I can only figure out a command that is in between 2 numbers instead of LEQ and GEQ